# Local extremum o a three-variable function

Tags: analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x,y,z)=x^2+4y^2+8z^2+4xy+6xz+12yz+8x+16y+24z$.

Find its local extremum points.

I find that the critic points are: $(-2a-4,a,0) , \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Unfortunately, the Hessian matrix has a null determinant. I tried to use the second differential theorem and to look at the difference:
$$ f(x,y,z)-f(-2a-4,a,0)=f(x,y,z)+16, $$
but, nothing.